# Pause a for loop until external callback method is called

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, telegram, subscription

**Non-technical explanation of what I'm trying to do:**

I have a bot that sends a user a picture, when the user clicks the "done" button it sends him the next picture, and so on until there are no more pictures.

**Problem:**

The only way to listen to that button using the API I'm using is by using this method:

```
private static async void BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs callbackQueryEventArgs) {
        var callbackQuery = callbackQueryEventArgs.CallbackQuery;
        try {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(callbackQuery.Id, "Answer has been submitted");
                string data = callbackQuery.Data.ToLower();
                if (data.Equals("notfound")){
                    //TODO He couldn't find the item
                }
                else if (data.Equals("done")) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And of course, subscribe to it via:

```
Bot.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallbackQueryReceived;
```

To send the image and menu, I have a for loop that covers a `List<Item>` (`Item` is a POCO).

```
await Task.Run(() => {
            // - Which buttons to send. MenuItem's constructor is (ButtonText, Callbackdata)
            List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
            menuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Done", "done"));
            menuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Not found", "notFound"));
            //telegramLineItemObjects is a List<Item>
            foreach (Item item in telegramLineItemObjects) {
                string message = $"<b>Shelf Number:</b> {item.ShelfNumber}\n<b>Sku:</b> {item.Sku}\n<b>Barcode:</b> {item.Barcode}\n<b>Description:</b> {item.Description}\n<b>Quantity:</b> {item.Quantity}\n";
                //sendImage(Image URL, message, message parse mode)
                telegram.sendImage(item.Picture, message, ParseMode.HTML);
                Message sentMenu = telegram.sendMenu(message, menuItems);
            }
        }
```

I want to pause the `for` loop, wait for `BotOnCallBackQueryReceived` to be called, then resume the for loop.

**To do that, I need a way to listen for when `BotOnCallBackQueryReceived` is called. How do I do that?**

Comment: Instead of attempting to use a loop, try a different control flow. Pull first item from list and send message/image. Then anything further message/image sending will just be triggered in the callback/event handler. For each risen OnCallbackQuery event, let the callback/event handler pull the next item from the list and send message/image for that item. This process will self-perpetuate until list is empty.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?